# Datatables with nested array

Tags: datatables

I've posed a question about [Bootstrap Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696281/processing-nested-arrays-in-bootstrap-table) but meanwhile I moved to Datatables as I was feeling blocked. My problem, however, is the same.

None of the two can easily handle nested JSON results. For instance if I choose "field: author", it processes the following as "[Object Object], [Object Object]".

```
    "author": [
        {
            "family": "Obama",
            "given": "Barack"
        },
        {
            "family": "Obama",
            "given": "Michelle"
        }
```

I can select the results individually, say "field: author[, ].family", which returns a list like "Obama, Obama". But I want an output like "given+family1, given+family2, ..".

Comment: Datatables can easily [handle nested json](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/deepObjects.html). Maybe if you posted your datatables code someone might be able to help you. What is your question?

Comment: Isn't Editor a paid plugin?

Comment: Gaa sorry, I pasted the wrong link! [https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html)

Comment: I've already been through this. You can call JSON sub-objects using "value.[position].child". What you cannot do is call all the child entities of "value".

So at best I can have the output "Obama, Obama". But I want it to be "Barack Obama, Michelle Obama".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom rendering. DataTables allows you to define custom rendering for each column.

Here is a [sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/g9eCs7oEeVvIGQhATRKk?p=preview) that I worked out. I am doing custom rendering for Author column.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dataSet = [
    { "name": "How to DataTables", "author": [{ "firstname": "jack", lastname: "d" }, { "firstname": "dick", lastname: "j" }] },
    { "name": "How to Custom Render", "author": [{ "firstname": "bill", lastname: "g" }, { "firstname": "scott", lastname: "g" }] }
];

$('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { title:"Book Name",
          data: "name" },
        {
          title: "Authors",
            data: "author",
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                //return data.length;
                var txt = '';
                data.forEach(function(item) {
                    if (txt.length > 0) {
                      txt += ', '
                    }
                    txt += item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname;
                });
                return txt;
            }
        }
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: Ok this works but I don't know how to use it with a JSON file. I need to convert the JSON input to variables I can then play with and interchange.

Comment: There are ways you can load data directly into Datatables, see this link https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/

Comment: Solved in the Datatables forum:

`"data": "author",
        "render": function ( data, type, full ) {
        return $.map( data, function ( d, i ) {
        return d.given +' '+ d.family;
        } ).join( ',<br />' );
        }`